# 企業ページから企業理念などの情報を抽出

Tags: python, python3

Pythonで企業のホームページから企業理念などの情報を抽出したいので、企業理念や社長のメッセージなどのページに遷移してURLを取得するコードが書きたいです。

しかし、企業理念などは添付した写真で赤枠で囲ってあるよくわからないところに格納されているので、タグで取ってこれません。

どのようにすれば、企業理念などのURLを取得することができるのでしょうか。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: [企業理念 `site:https://global.toyota/`](https://www.google.co.jp/search?complete=0&q=%e4%bc%81%e6%a5%ad%e7%90%86%e5%bf%b5+site%3ahttps%3a%2f%2fglobal.toyota%2f&hl=ja&lr=lang_ja) で検索するなど。

Comment: https://global.toyota/jp/sitemap/